# How to change the version of library in Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager

I used some libraries in my swiftUI project with help of Swift Package Manager.

But I want to use some previous version of one library.

What I am tried:

[image]

If I change here it nothing reflects.

Can anyone suggest how to change the version of particular library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an exact version of the package that you want.

Just select the drop down beside **Up to next major** and choose **Exact**.

[image]

Then insert the exact version that you wish to use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought POD is better than SPM because of this issue. Can you suggest which one good?

Comment: Not all app dependencies are available as Swift Packages, so you may have to use Cocoapods for them. It is possible to use both in an application. I like SPM as I find it easier to use, and it doesn't rely on a third party framework to install the dependencies. It is up to you which you use, Cocoapods have been around for a long time and are a fairly well known and robust way of adding dependencies to an application. As I said, you can use both in your application if you need to.